# log int on SD with STM32 and fatfs

Tags: logging, sd-card, stm32

I want to log some data on SD card. I am using STM32f10x and my code works well for string. I have a problem to write int on my SD. I am using this code for writing:

> res = f_write(&fsrc, ramBufferWrite, filecounter, &bw);

Also, I tried sprintf and it did not work. I will be appreciated if you can help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Could we have some more details, perhaps a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

I used "itoa" function to change int to string. Also, I used "filecounter" for Initialization file buffer write.